# "dd-MMM HH:mm" Versus "dd-MMM HH:MM"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to apply date mask on date entered by user.
I come across the following two statements.

**HH** Hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock).
**MM**Minutes; leading zero for single-digit minutes.

When i use small (mm) i get the correct result but when i use MM it adds 3 minutes to minutes entered by user.

So, What is the difference between following two date masks

Mask 1:

```
dd-MMM HH:mm
```

Mask 2:

```
dd-MMM HH:MM
```

Comment: Could you please expand with examples of input/output and how you're doing the conversion from string to date?

Comment: I am just applying filter using cellFilter of ng-grid, you need more details?

Comment: Like this: cellFilter: "date:'dd-MMM HH:mm'",

Comment: If I know right "MM" is for Month and "mm" is for minute. Check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: thansk, seems i was referring wrong site. http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Relevant angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which datetime library you're using, but typically the case distinction between `MM` vs. `mm` means one is used to for months and the other for minutes. If `MM` is month then today it's 03 for March. Try `mm` instead.

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), a popular JS datetime library, uses this type of formatting. If you're using some other library you should refer to their docs.

Comment: Thanks, seems i was referring wrong blog: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Comment: Is it something wrongly mentioned on blog or there is an issue to my understanding?

Comment: The blog post you are reading is specifically documenting that author's own date library. The documentation for Angular's date formatting is https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date